Getting Sql Server minidumps every few min
Is there a site where I can upload a Sql Server minidump to get more information about what caused it?

Are you on the latest CU? A crash/dump is indicative of a product defect and should be communicated to MS.

Unofficially, you can upload them here: https://www.sqldumpanalysis.com/ - Erik Reasonable Rates Darling
